# Matplotlib polar bar-plot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data from a questionnaire that provides answers in 6 "dimensions" (each answer represents a value from 0-4). I'm trying to plot the averages for each of the 6 "dimensions" in a polar bar graph.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([2.83333333, 1.6, 1.75, 2.6, 0.875, 1.75])

N = len(data)
theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
radii = data
width = 2 * np.pi / N

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([0,1,2,3,4])
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['None','Mild','Moderate','Severe','Extreme'])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(theta)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([1,2,3,4,5,6])

ax.legend(['foo','bar','snafu','swag','s-fus','tarfu'])

for r, bar in zip(theta, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.jet(r / np.pi / 2))
    bar.set_alpha(0.8)

plt.show()
```

With the following as a result:

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/2rxaatc.png]

I've chosen to try using legends to name the bars as the actual descriptions will be rather long such as "Understanding and communicating". The alternative would have been to use x-tick labels between the major ticks (I don't have a good idea on how to do that either, but it would probably look bad anyway).

Now: WHY won't rest of the legends show up (I've randomly also gotten the second one, but that's about it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bars` is a `Container` object that contains the six `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`s that make up your bar plot. By default, `legend()` seems to treat it as a single artist, hence why you are only getting one legend item for your bars.

You can force `legend()` to draw separate legend items for each artist by calling it with the alternate syntax:

```
legend(sequence_of_artists, sequence_of_labels, ...)
```

Try this:

```
ax.legend(bars, ['foo','bar','snafu','swag','s-fus','tarfu'])
```

You will need to create the legend after you have changed the colors of the bars, otherwise the colors on the legend won't match the colors of the bars.

---

Another way to achieve the same result would be to set the `label` attribute of each bar, similar to how you are currently setting the colors. When each bar has its own `label`, `legend()` automatically treats them as separate and draws legend items for each one.

```
...
labels = ['foo','bar','snafu','swag','s-fus','tarfu']
for r, bar, ll in zip(theta, bars, labels):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.jet(r / np.pi / 2))
    bar.set_alpha(0.8)
    bar.set_label(ll)

ax.legend()
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Also apparently the ax.legend -line needs to be also added after the color formatting instead of before it (like in my question), or the colors won't match.

Comment: @JoonasJoensuu Yep, I've also added a second method to achieve the same result using `set_label()`